# Illustrator pathfinder tool cutout not working

Tags: adobe-illustrator, pathfinder

Hey guys I really need your help with one problem I am facing right now while working on a logo. I created a logo using a starburst effect, however when I use the pathfinder cut out effect the images gets thinner not only when I save it on PDF but also when I print it.

[image: original image]

Second image is already cut out. Doesn't look too obvious but it is thinner.
[image]

Third image is both images zoomed out next to each other, it becomes more obvious they don't look the same. It becomes a problem since it will be a logo that will need to be reduced.

Thanks in advance

[image]

Comment: Hi. Welcome to GDSE.  Can I ask, why do you need to cut it out? What problem are you hoping to avoid by doing that?

Comment: Hi Billy. I need to cut it out because it will be a logo and that will be negative space in the design

Comment: Do you mean something in the background will show through the star shaped hole?

Answer (score 1):

## Anti-Aliasing

- **White on color** anti-aliases the white to the color. Therefore the white area appears to get slightly larger in order to blend visually with the color under it.
- **Color on transparency** (or white) anti-aliases the color to transparency. The color area appears to get slightly larger to blend visually with transparency/white.

[image]

It's a visual anomaly in the preview based upon how colors/transparency is stacked.

If you check **Outline Mode** (`View > Outline Mode`) or turn off anti-aliasing in the *Preferences*, you should find both shapes are the same size. And it's merely the preview which is showing a variation. Monitors with a higher pixel density tend to hide this anomaly better. The anomaly is also *much* more prevalent when working with very small objects.

Comment: Nah its just that adobe does blending in the working space. Anf srgb is not linear. White does not have to do this.

Comment: .. but it does. That's all I'm pointing out `:)`

Comment: yeah but technically its wrong

Comment: My answer or Adobe's construction? I know Adobe's preview construction is bad.. but I think this answer correctly explains the issue.

Comment: Thanks for the answers.The same problem appears when printing the logo. Does that applies to the printed work as well? I wouldn't mind if it was just digitally, however it seems even worse when printed

Comment: @Starshine Printed how? On an inkjet printer or with a commercial press??  It shouldn't be an issue at all with a commercial press. Inkjet printing form Illustrator is typically a bad idea. Save as PDF and print the PDF using Acrobat or Reader.

Comment: Yes, printed with an inkjet printer for testing

Comment: @Starshine unless the inkjet has a Postscript Level 3 RIP (most do **not**) you will rarely get any sort of accurate print from Illustrator. This is why I recommend saving as a PDF and printing from Acrobat. Acrobat is a software RIP. Without a RIP.. the inkjet prints the low resolution preview image from Illustrator, not the ACTUAL vector data.

Comment: @Scott I tried doing that now, printing directly from Acrobat however the outcome still the same. Really frustrating